# What kind of terminal type or PS1 custamization is this?

Tags: 16.04, command-line, bash, ps1

The person in the k8s tutorial video from Ubuntu is using a cool looking shell prompt. I cant tell if its a terminal emulator doing this or a custom $PS1 variable or maybe its like byobu. Any one want to throw me a bone ?

https://www.ubuntu.com/containers/kubernetes

here is the video if you wont want to scroll down

https://player.vimeo.com/video/190300823?color=ffffff&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using powerline-shell in the video with the solarized dark color scheme (which is included by default in the terminal):

- https://github.com/banga/powerline-shell

Answer (score 0):

That's likely an implementation of `zsh` customized with [`oh-my-zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh). The special characters are provided by a [Powerline font](https://github.com/powerline/fonts).